# from json response uri - how to extract the json keys and values and validate them using ansible json query filter?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Using ANSIBLE: I am getting the json response from url and priting the response but unable to print the particular keys/values.   (please see the json response) in my script i would pass Service, so i want to print only particular version of a service under tags only.  for e.g i would pass abc as parameter to ansible playbook then i want to print version under that Tags. i tried json query filter but unable to get this.

```
- name: Get url response
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:8500/myurl...
    return_content: yes
  register: json_response

- name: print json_response
  debug:
    var: json_response

- name: print the response
  set_fact:
    msg: "{{ json_response | from_json| json_query('Tags['build=*')}}"
```

my json response would be like this.

```
"json": {
        "abc": {
            "Tags": [
                "version=3.5"
            ]
        }, 
        "xyz": {
            "Tags": [
                "version=4.6.2" 
            ]
        }, 
        "asd": {
            "Tags": [
                "version=9.1.2" 
            ]
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think https://serverfault.com/questions/722852/how-to-check-the-json-response-from-a-uri-request-with-ansible    may be helpful

Comment: The only thing about ansible here is that you need to apply `json_query` filter to `json_response.json`. As for JMESPath expression, please, spend some time at http://jmespath.org/ to figure out the expression itself.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov thank you. This link http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html is very helpful. Now i am able to get to the exact value.

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinSuvorov I am able to solve this. truely appreciate your guidance and letting me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

> The only thing about ansible here is that you need to apply `json_query` filter to `json_response.json`. As for JMESPath expression, please, spend some time at [jmespath.org](http://jmespath.org/) to figure out the expression itself.